# SQL Get Total Order From CTE Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, sql-order-by, common-table-expression

Using AdventureWorks2008R2

I have:

```
With CTE As 
( 
Select 2005 As [Year]
Union
Select 2006
Union
Select 2007
Union 
Select 2008
)
Select * From CTE
```

This will give me the years (row) from 2004 to 2008:

```
2005
2006
2007
2008
```

Now, I want to insert the total order of each year into these row.

The following code will give me the total order:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS [Year]
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
)
SELECT COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Year]
```

How should I code it (something like INSERT into)?

[image]

Comment: Why use a cte when a simple group by year(orderdate) would do? BTW shouldn't this be tagged sqlserver?

Comment: It this case you shouldn't use CTE. Its unnecessarily more complicated and longer then common qry. If anyone encounters this piece of code, he will look for what you meant and where the recursion is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS
( 
    Select 2005 AS [Year] UNION
    Select 2006 UNION
    Select 2007 UNION 
    Select 2008
)
SELECT c.[Year], COUNT(soh.*) AS TotalOrders
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
  ON c.[Year] = YEAR(soh.OrderDate)
GROUP BY c.[Year]
ORDER BY c.[Year];
```

If you are sure that every year has data use simple:

```
SELECT YEAR(soh.OrderDate), COUNT(*) AS TotalOrders
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
WHERE soh.OrderDate >= '20050101' AND soh.OrderData < '20090101'
GROUP BY YEAR(soh.OrderDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(soh.OrderDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
insert into table(col1,col2)
SELECT  year,COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM (
SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS [Year]
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader) as t1
GROUP BY Year
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (year_col,total_order_col)
SELECT YEAR(OrderDate) AS [Year] ,COUNT(1) AS Total_Orders
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate)
```